# Converting contours from vector of cv::Point in cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, data-structures, contour

Suppose my objective is to extract contours from an initial image. I performed this operations using OpenCV:

```
cv::Mat gray, edges;
cv::cvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGRA2GRAY);
cv::Canny(gray, edges, 100, 300, 3);

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv::findContours(edges, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_TREE, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0));
```

Now the contour is contained in an array of Points. I want to rebuild a cv::Mat structure having the same dimensions as the initial image, so as to emphasize the contour by superimposing it to the image.

In particular, I am not interested in drawing immediately the contour. I will perform the following operations:

- extract the contour
- dilate the contour
- superimpose the contour on the image (as you do in edge sharpening)

Thus, the contour has to be a matrix of the same size of the input image.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want a Mat picture in the end with just the contours showing?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Then, by doing image-contours, I emphasize the contours.

Comment: I work a lot with contours for path finding but honestly I don't understand what you wanna do! sorry that couldn't help

Comment: your contours are lists of points, *not* an image. maybe you got that wrong ?  1.: you don't need to 'extract' the contour ( you've already done that ) 2.: you don't dilate a pointlist ( but maybe you want approxPoly there ) 3.: to superimpose it, - you just draw it to an image

Answer (score 1):

You can re-built a Matrix

```
Mat image_contours_grayscale = Mat::zeros(gray.size(),gray.type());
Scalar color(255);
drawContours( image_contours_grayscale, contours,-1,color,1);
```

I'm not sure if drawContours works with grayscale image, but if it doesn't, you can try this

```
Mat image_contours_color = Mat::zeros(image.size(),image.type());
Scalar color(255,255,255);
drawContours( image_contours_color, contours,-1,color,1);
Mat image_contours_grayscale;
cv::cvtColor(image_contours_color, image_contours_grayscale, CV_BGRA2GRAY);
```

image_contours_grayscale should be a grayscale image, all black with the contours in white.

Let me know if this works, I didn't have the occasion to test this solution !